# Writing binary string as mp4 python

Tags: python, binary, mp4

Here is what I have:

```
def write_binary(binary_string):
wfile = open('binary.mp4', 'wb')

for b in binary_string:
    wfile.write(b)
wfile.close()
```

The binary_string is a string containing binary data gotten from a url as an mp4. The file is stored locally and it plays. However, the video plays for zero seconds when it's 11 seconds long.

I think that it might have to do with the encoding unless open() takes care of that. It could also be the iteration over binary_string. Any suggestions please?

**EDIT**

```
  with open('binary.mp4', 'rb') as wfile:
      wfile.write(binary_string)
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you `close()` the file?

Comment: I did and still got nothing. Thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: What happens if you write `b` all at once without the `for` loop?

Comment: @Xaranke same thing. That makes me think it's something with the writing of the file. The size of the file its 3.1MB if that helps at all.

Comment: I know this is a long shot, but what happens if you use the `with` statement to open the file as shown here: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects ?

Comment: Why are you itearating through a binary string? Just write the whole string into the file: `wfile.write(binary_string)`. And just for checking, can you do a `print(type(binary_string))` before that?

Comment: @Xaranke still no difference. Check EDIT

Comment: @ViktorKerkez, I tried both approaches, iterating and writing as you mentioned. binary_string is <type 'str'> as expected. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Then (if you are using Python 2) you're doing everything the right way, and the problem is not in the writing part of the application, but in the creation of the `binary_string`.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez, you could be right. I get the mp4 binary from www.googleapis.com. I'd provide a link but it'd be useless without the appropriate header. It really bothers me the fact that the video opens up with QuickTime with a length of zero seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above works fine. Open the file as binary and call the write() method with a string containing binary.